# How to overriding specific Omega_Kickstart CSS files in a subtheme?

Tags: commerce, theming

I'm using Commerce Kickstart (Version 2).

I created a new theme, which is basically a copy of the commerce_kickstart_theme. So it's a subtheme of omega_kickstart which is, itself, a subtheme of omega v3.

Even though the child theme has various css files for global, narrow, normal, it -looks- as though the theme actually reads in the css from the parent theme... ie. the OMEGA and is ignoring same-named files in my subtheme.

Eg. if I have a file global.css in my subtheme, it is ignored and the omega_kickstart/global.css is used instead.

The same goes for the various alpha files. Eg. I copied alpha-mobile.css into my theme folder. But the file being @imported is the /omega/alpha/css/alpha-mobile.css.

My understanding is that if a same-named css file was in your theme directory it -replaced- the file from the parent. But that doesn't seem to be happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you may want to check (since none of these items are incuded in the question):

- make sure you cleared the cache (if not that explains what you experienced).
- make sure the file permissions are correct (if not the webserver will not be aware of the newly created subtheme).
- make sure you enabled the sub-theme (only creating it is not sufficient).